# measuring battery drain rate of a mobile device

Tags: java-me, nokia, battery

I am developing an application for a Nokia mobile device using J2ME. I am doing software testing now, my question is about is there any tool or methodology that enables me to measure battery drain rate of my application when it is running? i.e. how many hours or minutes the battery of the mobile device should stay when my application is running?.

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly I know nothing about J2ME, but if there's a way to query the amount of battery power remaining you could simply poll that value at a set interval and then extrapolate the amount of time it would take to get to 0% remaining?

**EDIT**
It looks like the property to access the battery percentage is:

```
System.getProperty("com.nokia.mid.batterylevel");
```

Source: [Nokia Dev Docs](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?132313-Get-Battery-Level-in-J2ME&s=2a6ace113f971e58df20f82c9321cc3e&p=410150&viewfull=1#post410150)

Comment: I believe this is the only viable approach.

Comment: Thanks kdmurray, it is better than nothing, I will try it in Nokia E66, hope it can work